# What does it mean when they say "switch to 32K " during the Phoenix Mars entry

Tags: mars, reentry, communication, radio-communication, phoenix

In the Phoenix Mars entry video

they keep saying "Odyssey switching to 32k", "Stop of Odyssey *unintelligible* Data and switch to 32k",and "We have Odyssey locked up onto Phoenix Carrier"

What is "32K" and "locked up onto Phoenix Carrier" mean? And why are they doing it?

Comment: ....bit rate?  32kb/sec, down from 64?  Lower bit rate = higher S/N and so fewer errors.

Comment: @MartinJames I suspect that it was an increase in the data rate rather than a decrease.

Comment: Partial answer: The Phoenix lander transmitted data to the Odyssey orbiter during Phoenix entry, descent, and landing (EDL), and the orbiter in turn relayed the received data to Earth. In order for this to happen, the Odyssey orbiter had to lock onto the signal transmitted by the lander.

Comment: Did it had to lock back to the lander because it lost contact during entry